Scaling property of a norm
Does a norm (generally in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for the purpose of the question in $\mathbb{R}^2$) satisfy the following property:$$||(a,b)||\geq||(a,0)||$$Where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. I'm certain this is true, but am having trouble proving it. This can probably be done relatively quickly using the equivalence of all norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but is it doable without it? Just by using the triangle inequality and other general properties of norms?

Consider the norm $\Vert (a,b) \Vert = \sqrt{(a-b)^2 + \epsilon b^2}$ for some small $\epsilon>0$. It is easy to show that this is indeed a norm on $\mathbb R^2$ (it follows from a weighted inner product). However, $\Vert (a,a) \Vert < \Vert (a,0)\Vert$ for any $a\ne 0$.

@John This is not true for norms generically, but it is true for symmetric gauge functions
